# Distinguishing mother from sister using autosomal DNA matches

Tags: autosomal-dna, relationship-analysis

M (female) matches F (female) with 2923 cM half identical (51 segments) and 866 cM (identical) on 37 segments.  Longest segment is 184 cM on the X chromosome.  Have a 135.04 segment on another chromosome.  50.92% shared DNA.

Is F (deceased) likely my Mother or sister?  Where does this total cM put F in relationship to M?

Comment: Which DNA test did you take?

Answer (score 0):

[DNAPainter](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/2923) says that a 2923 cM match is a "sibling".

Comment: 2923 cM is the half-identical regions only, if I understand the question correctly the total match is 3789 cM (2923+866).

Comment: 3789 is the total cM match through 23&me. DNA painter says the identical regions are counted twice. If that is true, then total cM shared is 3356.